# Parsing variable string with regular expression

Tags: regex

How can I select a variable in a string?

My string is

```
?aa=56345634563456&bb=16843621384
```

I tried to use this expression:

```
(\?|\&)aa=([^&]*)
```

Giving me this result:

```
?aa=56345634563456
```

I want to select only value **without aa=**, only this value:

```
56345634563456
```

How can I select that value using regular expression?

PS: my english is not so good, thank you for understanding

Comment: did you want the values of both variables `aa`,`bb`?

Comment: You need to refer to your second matched group in order to print only the match result. Also instead of the first capturing group, use a character class `[?&]aa=([^&]+)` then reference the first group for your match result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `(\?|\&)aa=([^&]*)` is correct. But you need to print the second captured group instead of printing the whole match.

The below regexes would match only the values, you don't need to go for a capturing group. So  printing the whole match wouldn't be a problem when you use the below regexes.

Try the below regex if you want to match the values of both variables `aa` and `bb`,

```
(?<=[?&](?:aa|bb)=)[^&]*
```

If you want to match the value of `aa` only, then try the below,

```
(?<=[?&]aa=)[^&]*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sB7nQ7/2)

In javascript,

```
> "?aa=56345634563456&bb=16843621384".match(/[?&]aa=([^&]*)/)[1];
'56345634563456'
```

**OR**

```
> var s = "?aa=56345634563456&bb=16843621384";
undefined
> var re = /[?&]aa=([^&]*)/g;
undefined
> function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
... index || (index = 1);
... var matches = [];
... var match;
... while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
..... matches.push(match[index]);
..... }
... return matches;
... }
undefined
> var matches = getMatches(s, re, 1);
undefined
> matches
[ '56345634563456' ]
```

Comment: (?<=[?&]aa=)[^&]* this is i want and it not work in javascript. php and python only

Comment: did you want a js solution?

Comment: thanks for helping me. I tried few couple way and I found this solution <script>string='?aa=56345634563456&bb=16843621384'; 

newString = string.match(/[?&]aa=([^&]*)/)[1]; 

console.log(newString);</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
    (?<=aa=)(\d+)
```

This should do it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/8

Comment: thank u for answer. but 56345634563456 numbers is always not a number. it could be a5s5da6 or -asdas-23_asda-a

Comment: i merge with your answer with @hwnd 's answer (?<=aa=)([^&]+)